# setHomeAsUpIndicator() for my actionbar in Android Studio doesn't appear to be working

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am changing the default arrow in the actionbar to a dropdown menu icon. Here is the code for my actionbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);
```

The problem is, the icon has not changed from a back arrow to a menu icon. The menu in drawable is a jpg file, so I don't see why there would be issues using it to replace the back arrow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whats the file size? And have you tried using a PNG file instead?

Answer (score -1):

Try `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           etSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.upbutton);`

Here is [the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215379/change-custom-up-back-button-icon-on-android-actionbar).

Comment: It didn't appear to do anything at all. I tried changing the drawable I pass to setHomeAsUpIndicator() to other images, but they all had the same outcome.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Code:-

```
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_arrow_icon_drawable);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and Override this Method :-

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Hope it will helps you